# map memory addresses to line numbers using DWARF information

Tags: debugging, dwarf

I have an application that traces program execution through memory. I tried to use `readelf --debug-dump=decodedline` to get memory address / line # information, but the memory addresses I see don't match up often with the ones given by that dump. I wrote something to match up each address with the "most recent" one appearing in the DWARF data -- this seemed to clean some things up but I'm not sure if that's the "official" way to interpret this data.

Can someone explain the exact process to map a program address to line number using DWARF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the program `addr2line`. It can probably give you some guidance on how to do this, if not solving your problem entirely (e.g. by shelling out to it, or linking its functionality in).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as mentioned by Phil Miller's answer, `addr2line` is your friend.  I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jc-gonzalez/27daa915eeb6d79188fd1570ca5a66cb) where I show how I get the line number in the (C++) application source code from an address obtained from a backtrace.

Following this process will not show you the process you mention, but can give you an idea of how the code gets mapped into the object code (in an executable or a library/archive).  Hope it helps.